# Twisted Python, TLS and client/server certificate authentication error

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, twisted

I've been learning Twisted as best I can, but together with limited TLS knowledge it's proving challenging. I'm trying to write (ultimately) an SMTP server that can send and receive messages both as plain text, or via TLS depending on requirements of a specific message to be sent / received.

My sample server code (thus far, just handling the TLS connection, no SMTP bits yet!) is borrowed from http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#auto5 and looks like:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import reactor, ssl
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class TLSServer(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "received: " + line

        if line == "STARTTLS":
            print "-- Switching to TLS"
            self.sendLine('READY')
            ctx = ServerTLSContext(
                privateKeyFileName='SSCerts/serverkey.pem',
                certificateFileName='SSCerts/servercert.pem',
                )
            self.transport.startTLS(ctx, self.factory)


class ServerTLSContext(ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        kw['sslmethod'] = SSL.TLSv1_METHOD
        ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = TLSServer
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

while the client is borrowed from http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#starttls-client and looks like:

```
from twisted.internet import ssl, endpoints, task, protocol, defer
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.python.modules import getModule

class StartTLSClient(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("plain text")
        self.sendLine("STARTTLS")

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print("received: " + line)
        if line == "READY":
            self.transport.startTLS(self.factory.options)
            self.sendLine("secure text")
            self.transport.loseConnection()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(StartTLSClient)
    certData = getModule(__name__).filePath.sibling('servercert.pem').getContent()
    factory.options = ssl.optionsForClientTLS(
        u"example.com", ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)
    )
    endpoint = endpoints.HostnameEndpoint(reactor, 'localhost', 8000)
    startTLSClient = yield endpoint.connect(factory)

    done = defer.Deferred()
    startTLSClient.connectionLost = lambda reason: done.callback(None)
    yield done

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import starttls_client
    task.react(starttls_client.main)
```

But when I have the server listening, and I run the client I get:

```
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py:30: DeprecationWarning: twisted.internet.interfaces.IStreamClientEndpointStringParser was deprecated in Twisted 14.0.0: This interface has been superseded by IStreamClientEndpointStringParserWithReactor.
  from twisted.internet.interfaces import (
main function encountered error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "starttls_client.py", line 33, in <module>
    task.react(starttls_client.main)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 875, in react
    finished = main(_reactor, *argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/pytho

n2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1237, in unwindGenerator
        return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1099, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)
      File "/root/Robot/Twisted/starttls_client.py", line 22, in main
        u"example.com", ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 619, in loadPEM
        return Class.load(data, KeyPair.load(data, crypto.FILETYPE_PEM),
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 725, in load
        return Class(crypto.load_privatekey(format, data))
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 2010, in load_privatekey

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 22, in exception_from_error_queue

OpenSSL.crypto.Error: []
```

The strange thing is - I know the certificate and key are fine - I have other "dummy" code (not pasted here, I figured this post is long enough!!) that uses them for validation just fine. Can anyone explain where the code above falls over? I'm at a loss...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there is a bug in the sample code found at: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html

Looking at the example "echoclient_ssl.py" there is the line:

```
authority = ssl.Certificate.loadPEM(certData)
```

However, the equivalent bit of code in the "starttls_client.py" example code is:

```
ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)
```

PrivateCertificate on the client side? Even with my limited understanding of TLS, this seems wrong. Indeed, I modified my code to remove the "Private"... and the error above disappears!

As I say, my knowledge and understanding is growing here - but this certainly seems to be the issue / solution to my question!